# SQL query with specific order of user actions

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table that looks like this:

```
user_id   user_action      timestamp
1         action #2     2016-02-01 00:02  
2         action #1     2017-10-05 15:24
3         action #3     2017-03-31 19:35
4         action #1     2017-07-09 00:24
1         action #1     2018-11-05 18:28
1         action #3     2018-02-01 13:02
2         action #2     2017-10-05 16:14
2         action #3     2017-10-05 16:34
etc
```

My task is to write a query where I can see user sessions, where a user performs action #1, 2, and 3 in that specific order, with time intervals between actions less than an hour. For example, user #2 have a session

```
2         action #1     2017-10-05 15:24
2         action #2     2017-10-05 16:14
2         action #3     2017-10-05 16:34
```

Sorry for lack of my own attempt, as I am really stuck and don't know, where to start.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In what specific order?  Your example does not have any user with more than one action, so the question is quite confusing.

Comment: should actions be on the same day? for example if  action1 is done on 23:59 and action 2 on 00:01 should they be listed? or you want to see all the actions that happens on the same day?

Comment: @sia thanks for your reply! Actions can be on different days, but time between each action should be less than an hour.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your reply! Edited the question, hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with window functions `lead` and `lag` which get the values from the next and previous rows respecitvely.

```
select distinct user_id
from (select user_id,user_action,timestamp,
      lag(user_action) over(partition by user_id order by timestamp) as prev_action,
      lead(user_action) over(partition by user_id order by timestamp) as next_action,
      datediff(minute,lag(timestamp) over(partition by user_id order by timestamp),timestamp) as time_diff_with_prev_action,
      datediff(minute,timestamp,lead(timestamp) over(partition by user_id order by timestamp)) as time_diff_with_next_action
      from tbl
     ) t
where user_action='action#2' and prev_action='action#1' and next_action='action#3'
and time_diff_with_prev_action <= 60 and time_diff_with_next_action <= 60
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works as desired! It turned out to be much more complicated, than I thought. Would you be so kind, and give a hint, how can I add session start time and session end time (last action + 1 hour) to the output.